# Как правильно писать в данном случае?

Tags: синтаксис

Второй факт является следствием первого?
Второй факт является следствием из первого?

Comment: можно расширенный контекст?

Comment: @Буратино это весь контекст

Comment: *Второе событие является следствием первого? Второй факт вытекает из первого?* Надо грамотно сформулировать.

Comment: @oleedd ответите на мой вопрос о тавтологии?

Comment: Не вижу ничего плохого в той фразе. Значения слов существенно отличаются. Можно было бы вообще "за" включить в корень.

Comment: @oleedd ни в одном словаре "за" в корень не входит

Comment: Можно было бы... Но подходы редко меняют. Значение специфическое, не так, как в "передать", "выдать". Что здесь даёт приставка? Какое стандартное влияние? В каких ещё словах есть такое значение приставки? Похоже на "запас". В таких случаях есть "за" и "против". Большое "за" здесь в том, что нет слова "дание".

Comment: Тавтология на слух ощущается. То есть режет слух, когда тавтология. Это не чисто формальность. Иногда оно не критично, например, "нарисовал рисунок" звучит не так жёстко, как "открыл открытку". "Дать задание" вообще хорошо звучит, можно сказать идеально. Или у вас режет?

Comment: @oleedd просто другое не может подходить: стая ворон, низкая цена, придать значение, одержать победу, дать задание. Только этот вариант из всех не имеет прав на существование.

Comment: Чего-то не было оповещения. На слух тавтология не ощущается. Значения, можно сказать, не пересекаются (должно быть пересечение). Ну и есть же легальные плеоназмы (так их называю). Не раз такое обсуждалось. Они стали устойчивыми из-за частого употребления. Легальная тавтология, думаю, тоже есть. Но не считаю это тавтологией. Аа, это из теста... Так бы сразу и сказали. Тогда методом исключения... Надо же что-то выбрать.

Comment: @oleedd методом исключения и выходит этот вариант

Comment: Ну да. Только вот "не имеет прав на существование" — это очень жёстко.

Comment: @oleedd например, на ЕГЭ проверяющие считают даже "в конченом итоге" ошибкой, что уж про обычные тесты говорить.

Comment: Это разговорное, не литературная речь, неудивительно, что они так считают. При этом надо обозначить, что разговорные выражения нельзя использовать. А если вдуматься, то итог всегда конечный, то есть получается, что даже плеоназм. Но уже в некоторой степени стало легальным. "Дать задание", как по мне, звучит правильнее. В контексте школы можно заменить на "задать", но не скажешь, например, "задал помыть посуду".

Comment: @oleedd Как в соответствии с современными нормами русского языка правильно: "в конечном счете" или в "конечном итоге"? Ранее правильным было "в итоге" или "в конечном счете", а в "конечном итоге" считалось тавтологией.
Спасибо
Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Оба сочетания нормативны - и "в конечном итоге", и "в конечном счете".

Comment: @oleedd Грамотно ли сказать: в конечном итоге? Или это избыточно, как "масло масляное"?
Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Это выражение грамотно.

Comment: @oleedd ни одной пометы, что оно разговорное

Comment: @oleedd Добрый день! Одно из заданий ЕГЭ по русскому языку - это нахождение плеоназмов. Является ли ошибкой наречное сочетание "в конечном итоге" (значение слова итог: результат, конец)?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Это выражение - плеоназм, но при этом его использование в речи корректно.

Comment: Ну, видимо, уже считается легальным плеоназмом. Ну вот, они даже об этом сказали. Избыточность явно в этом есть, в отличие от "в конечном счете". Только в БТС есть, этого мало, чтобы утверждать, так как нередко в одном словаре помета есть, а в другом нет. Мне кажется разговорным, в научной литературе так не напишешь.